# Python: lazy iterating through directory-like structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, generator

I'd like to apply a function through a directory-like structure. As Python 3 supports lazy generators, I thought about using these to lazy evaluate the resulting list. This was my approach:

```
iterate = lambda func, d: (func(f) for f in listDir(d) if not f.isDir) + sum((iterate(func, d + f.name) for f in listDir(d) if f.isDir.), [])
```

This leads to `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'list'`. Is there an idiomatic way to express this with lazy generators?

`listDir` accepts a path and returns a list of file information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that the order isn't important, I think it would typically be written:

```
def iterate(func, d):
    for f in listDir(d):
        if f.isDir:
            yield from iterate(func, d + f.name)
        else:
            yield func(f)
```

`yield from` only exists from Python 3.3, before that you can do:

```
for x in iterate(func, d + f.name):
    yield x
```

If you do need to string generators together, then `itertools.chain` and `itertools.chain.from_iterator` are the standard tools for the job:

```
def iterate(func, d):
    return itertools.chain(
        (func(f) for f in listDir(d) if not f.isDir),
        itertools.chain.from_iterable(
            iterate(func, d + f.name) for f in listDir(d) if f.isDir)
        )
    )
```

Comment: Isn't the use of listDir defeating the porpuse of lazily generating the files?

Comment: Depends how lazy you want it to be. I went with what the question was already using, but if you want to be able to exit early in the middle of listing a particular directory then I think scandir can do that: (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir). I haven't checked the implementation, though.